# TableViewNavigationController issue- newbie

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a `TableViewNavigationController`. On my first page, i have displayed a table-view, and on the navigation bar there is a add button, where the user could add a record.

once the user clicks on the add button, a UIView will be displayed and the user could enter details and submit, and then when the user clicks on the `back` button on the `TableViewNavigationController`, the first page which contains the table-view is displayed with the added record.

But, for me multiple records are displayed, and when i restart the stimulator it shows the correct set of records. Why is this and how can i prevent this?

EDIT : Can someone tell me which method fire's when we click the back button of the `TableViewNavigationController` ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you updating the datasource of your tableview with the right array-data?
If not,

```
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

Should fix that.

Comment: i have already tried this, but sadly nothing hapence. any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to use the reloadData method for your tableView when returning to the table.  And possibly refresh your data.  Is it coming from an array or using fetched results controller?  Either way, it sounds like you're seeing odd results because the data has changed.

Answer (score 0):

You should show us some code, so we can help you more.

The method that get's called when you change a view is the viewWillAppear

Since you mentioned that you are reloading your Table Data Source, are you sure you are adding the new entry to your existing Data Source (your Array) ?

Is your Array an mutable Array, so you can add the new record to it?